# Bat file does not make any impact in registry?

Tags: registry

I had tried to disable the proxy...But it sucks....

The following bat file code does not make any impact in registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename this file to have a ".reg" extension and try to run again

Comment: No buddy itz not reflecting in REGISTRY.Anyhow thankq so much for info

Answer (score 0):

some times the reason is the fist line of this registry edit script i recommend you use registry add command line

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings /v ProxyEnable /d 0 /f
```